# Can Java recognize a type parameter, T, as a super type of some class?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, inheritance

Background:

I have 3 classes: A, B, C where they all extends "Super" and implements "Interface" and I want to write code that only uses only the methods from "Super" and "Interface"

Unfortunately, I don't have control over the source code of A, B, C, "Super", "Interface" to change the inheritance chain, so my next approach is to use Generics.

I'm on Java 6.

This is what I have and B and C are used elsewhere:

```
<T extends Super & Interface> void myMethodA() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T test = (T)getA();
}
```

If I remove the cast `(T)`, Eclipse gives error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from A to T`

If I keep the cast, `Type safety: Unchecked cast from A to T`

My deduction was, 'Eclipse (or Javac) doesn't recognize T as a super type as A. For confirmation, I changed to `T extends Unrelated & Interface`. Eclipse gave an error `Cannot cast from A to T`. My second deduction was, 'Eclipse can tell that T is not a super type of A'

Now, I'm confused because my deductions are in conflict.

Question:

1. Can/Does Eclipse (or Javac) recognize a type parameter as a super type of a class?

2.a If so, why should I cast with `(T)` to remove an error and still get a warning?

2.b If not, how does Eclipse give error when `T` is changed to `T extends Unrelated & Interface`?

Comment: Can you show the signature of `getA()`?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you call `<B> myMethodA()`? You can't cast an `A` to a `B`.

Comment: @Turing85 `A getA() return anInstanceOfA;`

Comment: When your method is capturing a type <T extends Super & Interface> it only resolves at assignments or explicit calling object.<Type>getA(), but in your case you can't never ensure that T is super of A unless you type both before.

Comment: @SLaks Nice catch, I forgot that `T` can be a parameter provided by the caller.

Comment: @SLaks I tried `this.<B>myMethodA()` and it actually works and I think it's because `T` is bounded by `Super` and `Interface` anyways.

Comment: @Sgene9: That's because of type erasure; your type parameter is effectively ignored.  It still makes no sense.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I'll take <Type>getA() as a typo of <Type>myMethodA() and I'm afraid that I don't understand what you mean by 'you type both before'. Also, if I can't ensure that `T` is a super of `A`, how does Java know that `T extends Unrelated...` is not a super of `A` and give me error?

Comment: It's a unchecked cast, so it only know that it is not at runtime, the warning is at compile-time. I said typing both before is creating a structure, methods and generics that ensure that a cast will be safe at the moment of compilation

Comment: @SLaks If my method signature had `<T>` only, I would agree with you and Java won't compile too. But `<T extends Super & Interface>` limits `T` as a sub type of Super and Interface which effectively makes `T` as a super of `A` even if `B` is passed in as `T`. That's my understanding of the idea behind this but I should agree that this is probably not the intended way of use.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos the error from `T extends Unrelated...` is a compile error that I get even if I perform an unchecked type cast. All of the error that I mention in my question are compile errors that Eclipse shows. May be Eclipse is being smarter than Java and is able to provide runtime errors before running.

Comment: Never rely on eclipse to validate your generics code. I have seen many cases where eclipse would not show error but the compiler would error out.

Comment: Try (T) this.<T>getA() cause A is really far from T, you may need aditional generics

Comment: public class MyClass {
    interface A {}
    static class B {}
    
    <T extends B & A> T get() {
          return (T) new Z();
    }   
    static class Z extends B implements A {}
}

Comment: Your answer is, keep the unsafe cast as T, cause it is what you need

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos `getA()` is `A getA() { return anInstanceOfA;}` and I don't have access to its source. `myMethodA()` does not have a return value. What's confusing me is that Javac (and I'm now convinced that it's not about Eclipse being smarter) can tell `T` is a wrong generic for type cast by giving error, but it can't tell `T` is a right generic by giving warning

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Thanks for the sample code to test. Unfortunately, I don't have modify access to `get()`. 

Try this,
public class MyClass { interface A {} static class B {} <T extends C & A> T get() { return (T) new Z(); } static class Z extends B implements A {} static class C {} }

this will give you an error, indicating that the compiler can tell the wrong from the right. But why can't it tell the right from the wrong by giving an unchecked type cast warning?

Comment: Generics are resolved at compile time

Comment: Only erasing the type would give runtime Exception (with your sample, add)     <T extends C & A> T get() {
          return (T) (Object) new Z();
    }

Comment: As your modified sample, looks like your Z doesnt will never extends C, another solution is to create a interface as proxy and maybe you can use the reflection Proxy.newProxyInstance